# How to set ie margins with javascript or vbscript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, vbscript

I want to get print out invoice but also wanna set margins and page size with javascript or vbscript or anything else. is there any tutorial about that ?

and would you share something about ie8 to get print out easly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a CSS print style sheet.  See "[the definitive guide](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)".  P.S. JQuery is a JavaScript library, not a programming language (contrary to the belief of some).

Comment: you are absoulutly right about jquery.I said JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT because of browser capabilities are restricted when we use only css.

Comment: I wasn't saying only use CSS. But CSS print stylesheets are basically essential when you want nice printouts /and/ nice screen views.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to have reliable printing is to generate PDFs server-side and have the client download and print those.